# Using javascript var in php to get wordpress attachment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Is is possible to use a javascript var in some php code? I want to grab the url of an attachment image in wordpress. This is currently what I have tried using.

```
<div id="image"></div>

<script>
var attachmentid = '8723';
var attachmenturl = '<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url('+attachmentid+'); ?>';

$('#image').append(attachmenturl);
</script>
```

Comment: but why you want in this way?

Comment: because im using the rest api to grab data using javascript and using foreach in javascript and im not sure if you can get image via javascript

Comment: @Oscar you would need to create an new `img` element and set the src to append it: `var img = $('<img />').attr('src', attachmenturl ); $('#image').append(img );` this should work if it is not supposed to be ansynchronus

Comment: @empiric i tired but dont quite understand, could you send me a full example of what i need to do?

Comment: @Oscar you are current just appending the image URL, but you have to create a html element first: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/221022/)